# Is there a way to disable "click in gutter to add breakpoint" in Xcode?

Tags: xcode4

Is there a way to disable "click in gutter to add breakpoint" in Xcode?

I keep accidentally adding breakpoints then having to delete them when I'm trying to click on the error icons that show up when there is a warning/error.

Or am I doing it wrong somehow, like I'm not suppose to click those ...

Comment: Oh god, I thought I was the only one

Answer (score 14):

I've been looking but I haven't found a way to disable it. However, I found that you can drag a breakpoint off the gutter to remove it which is more convenient than clicking "Delete Breakpoint" in the context menu.

Comment: Nice discovery. Helps. Thanks.

Comment: Sanity recovered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to alexcoco's answer, you can remove a breakpoint by placing the cursor on the line with the breakpoint and pressing <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>backslash</kbd>.